# Does changing alpha value change text?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield, interface-builder, ios8.2

For a UITextView or UITextField, when the alpha value is changed, it seems to change the text as well.  Is that true?

Is there a way to change the alpha on just the background and not effect the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changing the `alpha` for the `UITextView` or `UITextField` affects the entire control. If you want to adjust the alpha of the background, specify the `alpha` of the `UIColor` for the `backgroundColor`.

For example, for a translucent red background you could do:

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1];
```

or

```
textView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with buttons?  I tried it but it isn't having any effect.